# Matlab r2015a guide - cannot convert double to a handle

Tags: matlab-guide

In the past , I used Matlab 2013 and this code runs correctly and no errors , but now I use matlab r2015a and  when I run the code, I get the following error: `Cannot convert double value -10 to a handle.` I checked the Matworks website but the explanation is not very clear. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this? Thank you so much !

```js
function minhhoaxy(action,in1)

global DATA; 

if nargin < 1,
   action='start';
end;

if strcmp(action,'start'),
clf reset;
figure(gcf);
set(gcf,'Units','normalized','NumberTitle','off', ...
        'Name','Minh hoa GUI','backingstore','on');
min_x=-10;     
max_x=10;
x=0; 

uicontrol('Style','text','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.03 .03 .1 .05],...
         'BackgroundColor',[0 0.5 .5],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'ForegroundColor','white','String','Vò trí x:',...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center');
uicontrol('Style','text','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.15 .03 .05 .05],...
         'BackgroundColor',[0 0 .5],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
         'ForegroundColor','white','String',num2str(min_x));   
x1=uicontrol('Style','slider','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.2 .03 .25 .05],...
         'SliderStep',[5.0000e-004 5.0000e-003],...
         'Value',x,'Max',max_x,'Min',min_x,...
         'Callback','minhhoaxy(''setx'',1);minhhoaxy(''redraw'');');
uicontrol('Style','text','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.45 .03 .05 .05],...
         'BackgroundColor',[0 0 .5],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
         'ForegroundColor','white','String',num2str(max_x));   
x2=uicontrol('Style','edit','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.55 .03 .09 .05],...
         'FontSize',10','Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'String',num2str(x),...
         'Callback','minhhoaxy(''setx'',2);minhhoaxy(''redraw'')');
uicontrol('Style','text','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.64 .03 .05 .05],...
         'BackgroundColor',[0 0 .5],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'ForegroundColor','white','String','cm',...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center');
uicontrol('Style','Pushbutton','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.87 .03 .1 .05],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'Callback','minhhoaxy(''done'')','String','Thoaùt');
     
min_y=-10;
max_y=10;
y=0;
uicontrol('Style','text','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.03 .1 .1 .05],...
         'BackgroundColor',[0 0.5 .5],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'ForegroundColor','white','String','Vò trí y:',...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center');
uicontrol('Style','text','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.15 .1 .05 .05],...
         'BackgroundColor',[0 0 .5],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
         'ForegroundColor','white','String',num2str(min_y));
uicontrol('Style','text','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.45 .1 .05 .05],...
         'BackgroundColor',[0 0 .5],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
         'ForegroundColor','white','String',num2str(max_y));
uicontrol('Style','text','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.64 .1 .05 .05],...
         'BackgroundColor',[0 0 .5],...
         'FontSize',12,'Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'ForegroundColor','white','String','cm',...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center');
y1=uicontrol('Style','slider','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.2 .1 .25 .05],...
         'SliderStep',[5.0000e-004 5.0000e-003],...
         'Value',y,'Max',max_y,'Min',min_y,...
         'Callback','minhhoaxy(''sety'',1);minhhoaxy(''redraw'');');
y2=uicontrol('Style','edit','Units','normalized',...
         'Position',[.55 .1 .09 .05],...
         'FontSize',10','Fontname','VNI-Times',...
         'String',num2str(y),...
         'Callback','minhhoaxy(''sety'',2);minhhoaxy(''redraw'')');

     
dt=plot(x,y,'r.','EraseMode','xor','Markersize',50);
axis([-10 10 -10 10]);
grid;
DATA=[x;min_x;max_x;x1;x2;dt;y;min_y;max_y;y1;y2];

elseif strcmp(action,'redraw'),
    x=DATA(1);
    dt=DATA(6);
    set(DATA(5),'string',num2str(x));    
    set(DATA(4),'value',x);
    y=DATA(7);
    set(DATA(11),'string',num2str(y));    
    set(DATA(10),'value',y);

   
    set(dt,'XData',x);
    set(dt,'YDATA',y);
    drawnow;



elseif strcmp(action,'setx'),
    if (in1==1),
       DATA(1)=get(DATA(4),'value');   
    else
       min_x=DATA(2);     
       max_x=DATA(3); 
       x=str2double(get(DATA(5),'string'));
       if (x>max_x),
           x=max_x;
       end;
       if (x<min_x),
           x=min_x;
       end;
       DATA(1)=x;
    end
    
elseif strcmp(action,'sety'),
    if (in1==1),
       DATA(7)=get(DATA(10),'value');   
    else
       min_y=DATA(8);     
       max_y=DATA(9); 
       y=str2double(get(DATA(11),'string'));
       if (y>max_y),
           y=max_y;
       end;
       if (y<min_y),
           y=min_y;
       end;
       DATA(7)=y;
    end    
 
elseif strcmp(action,'done'),
    clf reset;
    clear global DATA
    close;
end
```

Comment: Post the *full* error message. Additionally, this code is horrendously confusing. Why are you generating all your UI objects twice? And don't put your handles into an array with other random doubles and then reference the array later. Just use the handles in your `set` calls or store the handles to your objects in their *own* array with explicit names so you know what you're using without having to go back and reference your `DATA` assignments every single time.

Comment: Starting in R2014b, [Graphics Handles Are Now Objects, Not Doubles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html?refresh=true).

Comment: this is full error  message:
'> In minhhoaxy (line 96) 
Error using matlab.ui.control.UIControl/vertcat
Cannot convert double value -10 to a handle

Error in minhhoaxy (line 99)
DATA=[x;min_x;max_x;x1;x2;dt;y;min_y;max_y;y1;y2];''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact that graphics handles [*used to be doubles* but are now *objects*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html?refresh=true). Because of this, you cannot create an array that contains *both* numbers and graphics handles (but you used to be able to do this). If you do, MATLAB will try to convert between types and fail. Your issue is at the following line

```
DATA = [x; min_x; max_x; x1; x2; dt; y; min_y; max_y; y1; y2];
```

The `dt` in the middle there is a graphics handle to a plot object and is causing the error that you are seeing.

```
dt = plot(x,y,'r.','EraseMode','xor','Markersize',50);
```

To avoid this you will need to use a different data structure than a numeric array.

A much better way to handle your data and graphics handle is to use a `struct` or a more understandable datatype. Something like the following.

```
DATA.x = x;
DATA.y = y;
DATA.dt = dt;
...
```

Otherwise you will need to use a cell array as that can contain *both* objects and numbers:

```
DATA = {x; min_x; max_x; x1; x2; dt; y; min_y; max_y; y1; y2};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in MATLAB 2016b, i.e. `Cannot convert double value 1138.95 to a handle`; for use of a double array with fourier slice theorem, in image reconstruction code. It was solved by simply typing `clear all` in the command line.

Comment: This really isn't a direct answer since it just means that you had a variable in your workspace that was interfering with the intended behavior. `clear all` could technically be the answer for every MATLAB question.

Comment: I find that about quarter to a third of all my error messages are resolved by the `clear all` command.

Comment: Right, it's the same as saying that turning your computer off and on again fixes most of your problems.